# With an Azure Function, can a single CosmosDB change feed be processed concurrently?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

With a CosmosDb-trigger function-binding to process a change feed, do I need to handle the possibility that multiple functions can be running concurrently, processing different parts of the change feed?

If not, am I right to consider that this means there is a potential performance bottleneck? (in that it may be possible for data to be ingested by multiple instances, faster than a single instance can process the feed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I need to handle the possibility. And there shouldn't be a performance bottleneck.

See Matias' answer at [cosmosdb-change-feed-scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273997/cosmosdb-change-feed-scaling), which goes into more detail.